# Convert String Data to Binary Image

Tags: string, image, qt, image-processing

I am using Qt and I am new to Qt. I am getting stream of string data from server in particular port.

I am receiving 1 and 0. each time I receive one line like this

```
1111110001111111111111111111100000000000011111111111
```

After getting `n` number of times I need to create binary image file from the data. `1` for white and `0` for black.

How to do this? I already implement the receiving data but I have no idea how to convert this data to image.

Please help me to find the solution for this problem.

Comment: Do u know the image dimensions?

Comment: yes. 500x500 image need to construct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try doing this way

```
    QImage Image(500,500, QImage::Format_Indexed8);
    for(int i=0;i<500/*image_width*/;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<500/*image_height*/;j++)
        {
            QRgb value;
            if(data[i*j] == 0)/*the data array should contain all the information*/
            {
                value = qRgb(0,0,0);
                Image.setPixel(i,j,qGray(value))
            }
            else
            {
               value = qRgb(255,255,255);
               Image.setPixel(i,j,qGray(value))
            }
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

- You must know dimensions of your image (for example `NxM`)
- According to dimensions of image, you must parse string what you got (think on how to write correct cycle to get `NxM` 2D array from 1D array consisting `NxM` elements).
- For holding your image data you can use `QImage` class. Create `QImage` object, passing to constructor `height` and `width`, use its method to `fill` image. For setting some color of pixel, you can use `QImage`s method `setPixel ( int x, int y, uint index_or_rgb )`.

Thats all. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

From Qt docs:
"Because QImage is a QPaintDevice subclass, QPainter can be used to draw directly onto images."

So, you can create QImage sized to 500x500

```
QImage image = QImage(500,500)
```

and then draw on this image

```
QPainter p(&image);
p.drawPoint(0,0);
p.drawPoint(0,1);
etc;
```

Another way is to save your bit stream into array char[] and simply create QImage with format Format_Mono or Format_MonoLSB.

```
QImage image = QImage(bitData, 500, 500, Format_Mono);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks For help i created image. here My Code

```
QImage testClass::GetImage(QString rdata, int iw, int ih)
{
    QImage *Image=new QImage(iw,ih,QImage::Format_ARGB32);
    for(int i=0;i<ih;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<iw;j++)
        {
            if(rdata.at((i*iw)+j) == '0')
                Image->setPixel(QPoint(j,i),qRgb(0,0,0));
            else
               Image->setPixel(QPoint(j,i),qRgb(255,255,255));
        }
   }
    return *Image;
}
```